# Facebook access token - How can i protect it correctly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a doubt. It's not a pure programming question but i'm confuse about it.
In order to access data through facebook graph APIs, facebook releases different type of access tokens: user-token, page-token, app-token and client-token.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/), it is not a good choice to insert the token directly into the code because anyone could get it by reverse-engineering the application. Their advice is to store it somewhere on a server, getting it calling a specific endpoint.This is a good idea if the application provides an authentication mechanism. In my case my application doesn't ask for credentials because the clients can only display some events of a specific page (they can't write, posts or do other similar stuff), so i could get the token calling some endpoint but the endpoint is open (there is not auth)! So i think that there's no sense hiding the token on a server.

Maybe i'm wrong, i asked this question because after some researches i found people who hides token in png images, who thinks that obfuscating the code is enough. Other people says that the better solution to obtain the token is calling a server but as i said i don't have an auth mechanism to use here.

I know that this question is at the limit with SO guidelines but I hope it can become a good point of reference for people like me who have asked themselves this question and struggle to find a definitive answer.

Thanks for your attention.

**Accepted answer:**
@WizKid

> No you can not have an endpoint that the users phone calls. The page
>   access token can not leave your server. If you send it to the users
>   phone it is possible for a user to access it and they can use it for
>   bad stuff. So what you need to do is have the user call your server to
>   get the data. And your server uses the page access token to get the
>   data from the graph API and then forward the information to the users
>   phone.

Comment: What access token are you talking about? A page or app access token you should never share with the user. A user access token you can only get if the user logs in which you say they don't.

Comment: I have an application that only displays events of a facebook page. It's requiring no login, currently im'using a page token stubbed in the code in order to call https://graphs.facebook.com/..... but i know that i should use an app token. There's no problem here stubbing the token in the code, but what if i want to preserve the page token or app token without stubbing its value in the code as string?? Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: You should never send the page or app access to the user in anyway. It should not be in the app and your server should not send it to the user.

Comment: I'm not sending anything to the user... i have an access token and i use it in order to make facebook apis calls. I'm speaking about "hiding" this token!

Comment: Where is the app running? Your server? The users phone/web browser?

Comment: The app is running on the users phone. To be clearer: the app displays some events from a facebook page, the user can send e-mails and other things, related to these events, to the administrator of that page. So the user doesnt need any authentication to open the app and view Facebook events. But an access token is required to call the Facebook graph API. Assuming that I'm using a page token, I can't put its value in a configuration file or anywhere else, according to fb docs I need to protect its value on a server.  I can create an endpoint to get the token but there is still no protection!

Comment: No you can not have an endpoint that the users phone calls. The page access token can not leave your server. If you send it to the users phone it is possible for a user to access it and they can use it for bad stuff.

So what you need to do is have the user call your server to get the data. And your server uses the page access token to get the data from the graph API and then forward the information to the users phone.

Comment: Oh it was the answer i was looking for. I know my question may seem silly but it really wasn't clear to me how to solve this. Now it's all clear for me. Thank you so much for your attention and support! I hadn't thought of such a simple thing, in fact it would have been a real vulnerability, but managing all server-side calls actually makes sense. Thank you again @WizKid :)